# Excel formula to pull random values and not duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I'm trying to get a sample of ID's from a excel file that has those ID's listed in column A. I want to avoid pulling the same ID two or more times when I use this formula. I'm trying to review 25% of these ID's each month with the ID amount changing each month.

Ex.
Month 1: Column A has 100 ID's (A2-A101), Formula will be in B2 cell but expanded out to B26 to grab 25 ID's without having any duplicate values within the 25.

Month 2: Column A has 200 ID's (A2-A201), Formula will be in B2 cell but expanded out to B51 to grab 50 ID's without having any duplicate values within the 50.

Currently I have the following formula that pulls a random ID from my excel file's column A.

=INDEX(A2:A423,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(A2:A423)),1)

When expanded out I still have duplicate ID's. Any help getting past this or an easier way to pull these ID's would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936252/randomize-a-list-of-numbers-atomaticaly-without-duplicates-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula in Office 365:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(INDEX(A:A,RANDARRAY(200,,2,201))),SEQUENCE(50))
```

Where the `200` is an arbitrary large number of returns.  It should be large enough to ensure that one gets at least as many unique numbers as desired.  The `2` is the beginning row.  The `201` is the ending row. And, the `50` is the number of returns desired.

[image]