# Random numbers chosen from a column

Tags: excel, random

Working with Excel, I am generating a random number in a single cell from a list of numbers in a column. I am using
`=@INDEX(Q2:Q18,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Q2:Q18)))`

I want to repeat this process in the next cells (like a quick-pick in the lotto system) but I don't want the values to repeat themselves from cell to cell. What do I need to add in my code to prevent a value repeating itself in another cell?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936252/randomize-a-list-of-numbers-atomaticaly-without-duplicates-in-excel

Comment: This one does not require the numbers in another column if they are sequential: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995826/generate-random-numbers-which-do-not-repeat-by-using-formulas?rq=1

Comment: Hi Scott, here is where I'm at with this: =AGGREGATE(15,6,$Q$2:$Q$24/(COUNTIF($X$24:Y24,$Q$2:$Q$24)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($Q$2:$Q$24)-ROW(1:1)+1)). The range from 2 to 24 is if it has to reach that many numbers. (which it doesn't most of the time) so from time to time, I get an error. My other issue is I need to enter the value "0" next to the first cell I'm working on